# Weak convergence in separable measure space (Stein and Shakarchi). Where did my proof go wrong?

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis

Recently, this was marked incorrect but I couldn't find my mistake.  I assume I made one.  Can someone point me to my error?

The problem is from Stein and Shakarchi's Functional Analysis:

Suppose the measure space $(X, \mu)$ is separable as defined in exercise $10$.  Let $1\leq p < \infty$ and $1/p+1/q=1$.  A sequence $\{f_n\}$ with $f_n\in L^p$ is said to converge to $f\in L^p$ weakly if
$$\int f_n gd\mu \to \int fg d\mu \hspace{2cm} \text{ for every } g\in L^q.$$

(b) Suppose $\sup_n ||f_n||_{L^p} < \infty$.  Then, to verify weak convergence it suffices to check the above for a dense subset of functions $g\in L^q$.

Exercise 10:
A measure space $(X, \mu)$ is {\bf separable} if there exists a countable family of measurable subsets $\{E_k\}_{k=1}^\infty$ so that if $E$ is any measurable set of finite measure, then
$$\mu(E\triangle E_{n_k})\to 0 \hspace{2cm} \text{ as } k\to0$$
for an appropriate subsequence $\{n_k\}$ which depends on $E$.  Here $A\triangle B$ denotes the symmetric difference of the sets $A$ and $B$, that is,
$$A\triangle B = (A-B)\cup (B-A).$$

I did the following:

Suppose $\sup_n||f_n||_{L^p} = M<\infty$ and $f\in L^p$.  Suppose that $\mathcal{B}\subseteq L^q$ is a dense subset so that for all $h\in \mathcal{B}$,
$$\int f_n h d\mu\to \int f  h d\mu.$$
Let $g\in L^q$ be an arbitrary function.  Now, since $\mathcal{B}$ is dense in $L^q$, there is a function $h\in \mathcal{B}$ so that
$$||g-h||_{L^q} <\frac{\epsilon}{3\cdot\max\{M, ||f||_{L^p}\}}.$$
Also, as $h\in\mathcal{B}$, by assumption, there exists $N$ so that for every $k\geq N$, we have
$$||f_k h - f h||_{L^1} <\frac{\epsilon}{3}.$$
For $k\geq N$, this gives
\begin{align*}
\Big|||f_k g||_{L^1} - ||f g||_{L^1}\Big| \leq& \, ||f_k g - f g||_{L^1}\\
=& \, ||f_k g - fg+\Big(f_kh-f_kh+fh-fh\Big)||_{L^1}\\
=& \, ||(f_k h - fh)+ \Big(f_kg-fg-f_kh+fh\Big)||_{L^1}\\
\leq& \, ||f_k h - fh||_{L^1} + ||(f_k-f)(g-h)||_{L^1}\\
\leq& \, ||f_k h - fh||_{L^1} + ||f_k-f||_{L^p}||g-h||_{L^q}\\
<& \, \frac{\epsilon}{3} + ||f_k||_{L^p}||g-h||_{L^q}+||f||_{L^p}||g-h||_{L^q}\\
<& \, \frac{\epsilon}{3} + \frac{\epsilon}{3}+\frac{\epsilon}{3}\\
=& \, \epsilon.
\end{align*}

Comment: mixing $L_1$ norm notation with absolute value notation. Not rigurous. The serveral places that $L_1 norm$ should be the absolute notation $||$.

Comment: I'm sorry I'm not quite understanding.  Could you please explain more?  What should I have instead?

Comment: I gave a detail explanation.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Let $<f, g> = \int fgd\mu$
\begin{align*}
|<f_k,g>- <f,g>|\\
=& \, |<f_k,g> - <f,g>+\Big(<f_k,h>-<f_k,h>+<f,h>-<f,h>\Big)|\\
=& \, |(<f_k, h> - <f,h>+ \Big(<f_k,g>-<f,g>-<f_k,h>+<f,h>\Big)|\\
\leq& \, |<f_k h>- <f, h>| + |(<f_k-f, g-h>|\\
\leq& \, |<f_k, h> - <f, h>| + ||f_k-f||_{L^p}||g-h||_{L^q}\\
<& \, \frac{\epsilon}{3} + ||f_k||_{L^p}||g-h||_{L^q}+||f||_{L^p}||g-h||_{L^q}\\
<& \, \frac{\epsilon}{3} + \frac{\epsilon}{3}+\frac{\epsilon}{3}\\
=& \, \epsilon.
\end{align*}

You use
$$||f_k h - f h||_{L^1} <\frac{\epsilon}{3}.$$,
This is wrong. Ity means $f_kh$ converge to $f\,h$ in $L^1$, which is not true. The correct weak convergence is
$|<f_k, h> - <f, h>| <\frac{\epsilon}{3}.$

You basically ignored weak convergence, instead, assume convergence in $L^1$